# Unsure which JS templating engine is being used

Tags: javascript, arrays, wordpress, handlebars.js

I have a page that uses templating in the follow manner. `{{= something}}`, without the quotes. (e.g. Find `{{=` in the page source of https://projectshop.thefussy.co/profiles/)

I thought that it was Handlebars, but AFAIK Handlebars doesn't have an equal sign in the double brackets. I've also tried using some of Handlebar's built-in helpers (https://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html) for looping arrays, but none of them worked.

Am I mistaken in thinking that Handlebars is being used? If so, how do I iterate through an array as I would with Handlebars' `each` helper?

Comment: `{` and `}` are used by many template engines, not just only by handlebars. `{{=` could be `doT` but also `underscore` and there are most certainly other template engines with the same syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses [UnderscoreJS](http://underscorejs.org/#template) templating engine with the following template settings ([source](https://projectshop.thefussy.co/wp-content/themes/freelanceengine/includes/aecore/assets/js/appengine.js?ver=1))

```
_.templateSettings = {
    evaluate: /\<\#(.+?)\#\>/g,
    interpolate: /\{\{=(.+?)\}\}/g,
    escape: /\{\{-(.+?)\}\}/g
};
```

here is an example loop with [UnderscoreJS](http://underscorejs.org/#template) templating and using the settings above.

```
<# if(list[‘person’]) { #>
  <ul>
    <# _(list[‘person’]).each(function(person) { #>
      <li>{{= person.name}}</li>
    <# }) #>
  </ul>
<# } #>
```